# Petersen Graph deleting an edge

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If you were to compute the number of spanning trees on a Petersen graph with one edge missing, how would you argue that what ever edge you delete, you will still get the same answer?

Answer (score 4):

This follows from the [*edge transitivity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge-transitive_graph) of the [Petersen Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph#Symmetries). In short, for any two edges $e_1$ and $e_2$ of the graph, there is an automorphism sending $e_1$ to $e_2$.

To put it in less technical language, a graph is edge transitive if all the edges "look the same". For example, the graph of a cube is edge transitive, as is the complete graph on $n$ vertices.